# Find values in array and return index

Tags: java, arrays

I want to return an array with the index's where the getElem() is equal or higher a certain value.

This is my function:

```
public static int []findIndex(BufferedImage image,int value)
{
    DataBuffer b = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
     int array[] = new int[600];
    for(int i=0;i<76400;i++)
    {
        if(b.getElem(i)>=value)
            array[i]=i;
    }
    return array;
}
```

but i have an error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27001
    at arraytest.imageMan.findIndex(imageMan.java:139)
    at arraytest.imageMan.main(imageMan.java:183)"
```

Comment: Print the index, I bet it must be greater than 599 !!!!! You are initializing the array with `600` , so anything greater than 599 will throw error !!!

Comment: Yes the problem is the size of the array..

Comment: Why do you loop to `76400`? Since your array is only stores 601 elements this might cause the problem?

Comment: @Kuchi The array stores 600 elements

Comment: I want search in my DataBuffer(76400 pos), which of then are equal to my value, and store it on array..I want only 600 values, so i declare my array with 600 pos.

Comment: So, what you're trying to do is make a list of the DataBuffer[] elements that match your value? What if there are more than 600 matches? Will you be satisfied with just the first 600? What if there are fewer than 600 matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final function.
How should we choose a generic programming,i made some changes that made ​​a focused precisely on that.
Use now have a list instead of a static array.

```
   public static int[] findIndex(BufferedImage image, int value) {
    DataBuffer b = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(20);

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.getSize(); i++) {
        if (b.getElem(i) >= value) {
            a.add(i);
            j++;
        }
    }
    int array[] = new int[a.size()];
    for (int k = 0; k < a.size(); k++) {
        array[k] = a.get(k);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 int array[] = new int[600];
```

The array you declare is of size `600`.

```
 for(int i=0;i<76400;i++)
```

Yet you attempt to reference the array at the `76400`'th index.

**Why doesn't this work?**

Well, when you say `new int[600]`, you are essentially saying, my array can store 600 things, and this means that it has 600 different "slots" to store values.

You access these values by their index, starting from `0`.

```
array[0] // First item
array[599] // Last item.
```

Your error has occurred because you have exceeded `599`.

**How to fix this**

Well, you can either make your array `76400` long, (which to me is suspicious), or you can change `76400` to `array.length` (or `600`) in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution i find..

I think that is the best..

```
 public static int[] findIndex(BufferedImage image, int value) {
    DataBuffer b = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
    int array[] = new int[600];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.getSize(); i++) {
        if (b.getElem(i) >= value) {
            if (j < 600) {
                array[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty good except what if there are less than 600 matches?

Comment: I don't test that possibility, but my image have 76400 pixels, so, i think it's hard don't have 600 matches.
This is an solution for that exact problem, for others, it's likely don't working..

Comment: Well in that case, it looks like you've found the answer to your own problem. You're allowed to mark it as such if you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your loop from 0 to 76400, which much much greater than the size of your array.

```
public static int []findIndex(BufferedImage image,int value)
{
    DataBuffer b = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
    int array[] = new int[600];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(b.getElem(i)>=value)
            array[i]=i;
    }
    return array;
}
```